# How do I make sure I purchase the correct replacement gfx card for my iMac?

Tags: hardware, hardware-recommendation, repair, gpu, maintenance

I have a [24" Early 2009 iMac](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP507?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), and it has a faulty graphics card ([detailed here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114206/what-is-wrong-with-my-imac-video-corruption-unstable)). I'm obviously no longer under warranty or applecare, and I'd like to try to [replace the part myself](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+24-Inch+EMC+2267+Graphics+Card+Replacement/13765).

I'm unsure about how to search for and select a replacement part, however, especially since my machine is quite old so the original gfx card model is probably not available new. How can I know that any given card listed on a hardware website will work as a replacement?

(A short list of appropriate gfx card model numbers would also suffice.)

Comment: Ok replacing the part, might be a bit risky but i will give you all details. What graphics card do you use? AMD? Intel? NVIDIA?

Answer (score 1):

The NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GS is not available anymore, but you can try the NVIDIA GeForce GT 680, which you can find here: http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=02G-P4-3682-KR
You will also need to upgrade your RAM to support this card. The RAM I suggest is here: http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/8566DDR3S4GP/

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to replace the part yourself, first you wanna make sure you buy the updated version of your graphics card. Click [Here](https://www.google.com/#q=shop+for+gfx+graphic+card&safe=active&tbm=shop)

These links might help : http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/switcher-hangout/127498-putting-new-graphics-card-into-imac.html

http://discussions.apple.com/thread/3029120?tstart=0

Hope this helps.