# Sourcing a replacement graphics card for an iMac

Tags: imac, hardware, hardware-recommendation, repair, gpu

I have a Early-2009 2.93 GHz 24" iMac, which has a faulty graphics card.

I'm keen to try replacing it myself using [this excellent guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iMac+Intel+24-Inch+EMC+2267+Graphics+Card+Replacement/13765#s46197). Unfortunately the guide doesn't mention any advice on finding/buying a replacement card.

Where can I find a card to buy online (or locally), and what do I have to check to know that the card will be an appropriate replacement?

Answer (score 1):

There were three gfx card options that went in this model:

- NVIDIA GT120 (256Mb): part #661-4991
- NVIDIA GT130 (512Mb): part #661-4990
- ATI Radeon HD 4850 (512Mb): part #661-5135

Searching for these cards by this "Apple Part Number" yields many online sellers. Ebay, macpalace.com, powerbookmedic.com, macpartsonline.com...

(How to get the apple part number for any given computer is a mystery to me, so if someone wants to elucidate, I will probably accept the answer.)

Comment: Part numbers are always printed on the actual part. Same applies to most hardware, such as car parts. They are itemized by Apple hardware vendors (e.g., iFixit, PowerBook Medic).

Comment: Thanks @cksum that's great to know. Is there anywhere to find "part manifest" lists for Apple products?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Apple is very secretive and also doesn't much endorse DIY repairs.

Comment: Shame. Woulda thought that repair shops would have access to some kind of manifest for each model though! Guess there would be limited practical need for them.

Comment: 3rd party Apple certified repair shops may have something like this. You could always visit one and ask them how they place their orders. But even in that case, they would deal with Apple direct, so I'm not sure it would be much of value (over and above what you find at places like iFixit). I'm also assuming that they would have to keep such details private (again, restricted by Apple's secrecy blanket).